# apt-get upgrade freezes while setting up udev

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, udev

i am trying to upgrade my debian system however it keeps freezing when trying to setup udev,

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ...
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ....
79 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/141 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,987 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up udev (215-17+deb8u5) ...
Adding group `input' (GID 101) ...
Done.
```

then after "Done." nothing happens, i have tried waiting for hours
i tried

```
~$ sudo apt-mark hold udev
```

however that doesnt seem to help

edit: after running  `dpkg --purge --force-all udev` and then `apt-get install udev`

i got made some progress however it now hangs on

```
root@debian:/home/user# apt-get -f install udev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  udev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 78 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/877 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,193 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package udev.
(Reading database ... 68912 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_215-17+deb8u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (215-17+deb8u5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up udev (215-17+deb8u5) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
calling: test
version 215
load module index
Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel commandline, ignoring.
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
timestamp of '/lib/udev/rules.d' changed
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-lvm-metad.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 24948 bytes strings
22841 strings (185496 bytes), 19873 de-duplicated (163517 bytes), 2969 trie nodes used
IMPORT builtin 'net_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:6
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:12
IMPORT 'write_net_rules' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules:138
starting 'write_net_rules'
'write_net_rules' [23983] exit with return code 0
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:5
IMPORT builtin 'net_setup_link' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:11
Config file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link applies to device eth0
RUN 'net.agent' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules:1
RUN '/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/$name' /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules:61
unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
calling: test
version 215
load module index
Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel commandline, ignoring.
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-lvm-metad.rules
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 25030 bytes strings
22854 strings (185632 bytes), 19880 de-duplicated (163577 bytes), 2975 trie nodes used
IMPORT builtin 'net_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:6
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:12
IMPORT 'write_net_rules' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules:138
starting 'write_net_rules'
'write_net_rules' [23996] exit with return code 0
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:5
IMPORT builtin 'net_setup_link' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:11
Config file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link applies to device eth1
RUN 'net.agent' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules:1
RUN '/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/$name' /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules:61
unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
calling: test
version 215
load module index
Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel commandline, ignoring.
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-lvm-metad.rules
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 25053 bytes strings
22865 strings (185686 bytes), 19889 de-duplicated (163610 bytes), 2977 trie nodes used
IMPORT builtin 'net_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:6
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:5
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' returned non-zero
IMPORT builtin 'net_setup_link' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:11
Config file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link applies to device lo
RUN 'net.agent' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules:1
unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
root@debian:/home/user# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up udev (215-17+deb8u5) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
calling: test
version 215
load module index
Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel commandline, ignoring.
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-lvm-metad.rules
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 25053 bytes strings
22865 strings (185686 bytes), 19889 de-duplicated (163610 bytes), 2977 trie nodes used
NAME 'eth0' /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules:8
IMPORT builtin 'net_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:6
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:12
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:5
IMPORT builtin 'net_setup_link' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:11
Config file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link applies to device eth0
RUN 'net.agent' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules:1
RUN '/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/$name' /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules:61
unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
calling: test
version 215
load module index
Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel commandline, ignoring.
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-lvm-metad.rules
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 25053 bytes strings
22865 strings (185686 bytes), 19889 de-duplicated (163610 bytes), 2977 trie nodes used
NAME 'eth1' /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules:11
IMPORT builtin 'net_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:6
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:12
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:5
IMPORT builtin 'net_setup_link' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:11
Config file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link applies to device eth1
RUN 'net.agent' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules:1
RUN '/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/$name --prefix=/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/$name' /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules:61
unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
calling: test
version 215
load module index
Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel commandline, ignoring.
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-lvm-metad.rules
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 25053 bytes strings
22865 strings (185686 bytes), 19889 de-duplicated (163610 bytes), 2977 trie nodes used
IMPORT builtin 'net_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules:6
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:5
IMPORT builtin 'path_id' returned non-zero
IMPORT builtin 'net_setup_link' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules:11
Config file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link applies to device lo
RUN 'net.agent' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules:1
unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

and does not go any farther

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with udev post-installation script.
 You can bypassed it by editing the udev post install configuration file.

```
~$ sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst
```

On the first line add.

```
exit 0
```

Comment: this worked, however, i got disconnected from ssh session in the middle of the next  ```aptitude upgrade```, but i could have already handled the damage done...   Bad bug, thank you